# How to use altair scale(zero=False)?

Tags: altair

When executing the following code I would expect the graph to not include zero, but instead start somewhere around the minimum point in the data shown on the y-axis.

```
import pandas as pd
import altair as alt

print(alt.__version__)

df = pd.DataFrame(data={"targets": ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'], "values": [0.91, 0.95, 0.97, 0.9]})
display(df)

alt.Chart(df).mark_bar().encode(
    x='targets:N',
    y=alt.Y('values:Q').scale(zero=False)
)
```

But I get this:

[image]

When applying `mean()` to the values I am showing on the y-axis, this solves my issue. But I don't understand why this is happening.

```
alt.Chart(df).mark_bar().encode(
    x='targets:N',
    y=alt.Y('mean(values):Q').scale(zero=False)
)
```

[image]

Does this suggest I should not use a bar chart for individual values?

Using a different encoding seems to support that. For example with a line the zero is excluded:

```
alt.Chart(df).mark_line().encode(
    x='targets:N',
    y=alt.Y('values:Q').scale(zero=False)
)
```

[image]

Comment: It might be a bug, it does indeed seem inconsistent. Side note: this kind of scale may easily produce a wrong or misleiding interpretation, in your second graph it seems like D has actually a zero value if you don't look at the numbers carefully, or if you do look at the numbers it could be unclear whether D is 0.9 or something below it (could be 0.8 or even 0.0 given that no bar is present). Similarly on first glance it seems that B is five times as large as A whereas the difference is only a few percent in reality.

Comment: Thanks for the Marijn. 
I am aware of the visual issue, but I do not know how to solve it. Above is a simplified version. In the real version I have 10 values all around 0.96+-1 and you can't see which one is the winner visually, because they are so close.
I could express the absolute numbers as a difference to the mean, but the mean itself is kind of arbitrary, so ...

Comment: I think your original graph, with the origin at zero, is the best one. It shows clearly that all values are high, it shows that they are close together, and it is still visible that A is higher than D for example (which is a difference of 0.01). If you still want to show only part of the graph then maybe the approach of the answer below would be good, but then with the origin at 0.8 or 0.7 for example, which would still kind of show that A and D are high values while also showing the differences more clearly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it has to do with the fact that bar charts are stacked by default (even when there is only one value) and the default stack is `zero` ([docs](https://altair-viz.github.io/user_guide/generated/core/altair.StackTransform.html)). So using`y=alt.Y('values:Q', stack=None).scale(zero=False),` works, but your lowest bar will become invisible (beneath the x axis).
For non-zero bar charts I prefer to use `domainMin` instead as you can set some offset.

```
a = alt.Chart(df).mark_bar().encode(
    x='targets:N',
    y=alt.Y('values:Q', stack=None).scale(zero=False)
)
b = alt.Chart(df).mark_bar(clip=True).encode(
    x='targets:N',
    y=alt.Y('values:Q').scale(zero=False, domainMin=df['values'].min()*0.99)
)

a | b
```

[image: plot]

Comment: Thanks debbes. That's exactly what I was looking for. 

I was trying to give a minimal example. But with respect to the missing bars, an alternative way to get to the result you showed would be to define the visual padding you want: ```alt.Chart(df).mark_bar().encode(x='targets:N', y=alt.Y('values:Q', stack=None).scale(zero=False, padding=50)
)```

Comment: Ah yes, the padding is indeed a much nicer solution. Thanks.